# Is there a way to tell if my host is throttling speeds by request threads?

Tags: web-hosting

I've been with my host as a reseller for almost 15yrs and lately i've been noticing how sluggish my hosted sites are. I've always chalked it up to isolated cases or just slow connection on the user side... but after so long it seems suspicious.

Of course contacting my host didn't help, they just keep saying there was nothing wrong with their service.

So i ran some test using site speed tools and my page of roughly 3MB takes about 15-20 seconds to finish!

looking at the external sources being loaded, yes sure there are a bunch of http requests (js, api, etc) but these are very small data sets only.

Long story short, I did notice something.

Loading a very basic HTML site with bunch of images statically coded to the doc is blazing fast.... but loading a similar designed site, slightly heavier but with lots of external sources (from the same host) is super slow... and i've noticed that, using firebug, though a bunch of AJAX and Image requests has been fired, i can see a lot of these threads just freezing or pausing and proceeding when the other threads complete...it's like the server is somehow slowing down my page load , or some threads thereof, as a way of bandwidth management?

If i load other larger websites like amazon, ebay, facebook, with so many or even some smaller sites not using AWS but loading a bunch of external assets, and i see the request threads all loading or progressing at the same time... some sites with a total page load of 8MB finishing in <2 seconds and my site with just 3MB reaching around 15seconds to complete.

I would like to know of a way to 
 1. determine if my host is being sneaky w/ their bandwidth by slowing down or limiting simultaneous thread loads.
 2. document or prove to them that this is the case indeed.

Is there such a way?

Comment: While this isnt an answer it could be as simple as that the host is overselling and the actual web server is running out of resources to a point where it's noticeable with page load time.

Comment: Like @Analog says :P   That would be my first assumption.